# how to get values from an arraylist passed as a parameter in js function from jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a called a **Servlet** and I am sending an `ArrayList` with request attribute from Servlet to JSP. I am calling a js function from the same JSP in which I am passing the `ArrayList` as a param to the js function. I want to retrieve the values from this `ArrayList`.

**Code as follow:**

```
<c:if test="${currentPage lt noOfPages}">   
    <a onclick="OnNextButtonClick(${currentPage},'${al}');">
       <Next>
    </a>
</c:if>   
   //Here al is the ArrayList

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function OnNextButtonClick(currentPage,al)
{
  alert("current page == " + currentPage );
  alert("current page == " + al);

  var arr = new Array();
  var arr = al.split(','); 
  alert(arr);
}
```

This arr is giving me values as follows:

```
[com.package@1def,com.package@fkbe23,com.package@546fhfg]
```

I want the values stored at this location.

Can someone help me?

Comment: And I want a pony.  Now what is your question. (Hint: "Can someone help me?" is not a question.)

Comment: I think the values of `arr` is object. extract it by using `.` and the members of that object you want to retrieve.

Comment: @LKTN.25 I tried it... I did arr[1].id ....It gave me an undefined as a value.

Comment: @JoeC I want the values stored at the locations mentioned above.

Comment: That is not a question.  It's a wish list.

Comment: Wait... where is this `.id` that you mentioned coming from?  My Javascript may be a bit rusty, but I don't recall that being part of a string object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all List  obj = dao.listimpl();this is java code you have pasted, try to paste the exact object which you trying to iterate.

Though i would recommend use a very lightweight javascript library Loadash which is very handy, when you are dealing with array/objects and looping through these items and many more util methods.

```
_.forOwn(obj, function(value, key) { } );
```

**Loadash - forOwn**

Iterates over own enumerable string keyed properties of an object and invokes iteratee for each property. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value, key, object). Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false